# Make the routes accessible to all the pages and components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i created a route inside app.js  However im trying to make this route accessible to any other pages. I have code inside components/navbar.js. However whenever i click home or about the link is changing. but the right content or body is not changing . Can someone help me how to do it? Thank you.

This is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-chaplygin-mj2p3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React Router v4** is used for the example in the official documentation.

https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-sidenav#react-router-v4-with-react-v16

[image]

So that if you implement the Routing according to that example, use **React Router v4**, not v5. You can use **v5 if you implement the Router in your application according to that version.**

I have fixed all issues in your application using **React Router DOM v4**.

**App.js**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
      {/* Wrap all elements using Route render prop */}
        <Route
          render={({ location, history }) => (
            <>
              <header>
                <GiHamburgerMenu onClick={() => setShowNav(!showNav)} /> &emsp;
              </header>
              {/* Pass location & history props to Navbar */}
              <Navbar show={showNav} location={location} history={history} />
              <Route path="/" exact component={(props) => <Home />} />
              <Route path="/home" exact component={(props) => <Home />} />
              <Route path="/about" component={(props) => <About />} />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

**navbar.js**

```js
const Navbar = ({ show, location, history }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <SideNav
        onSelect={(selected) => {
          const to = "/" + selected;
          if (location.pathname !== to) {
            history.push(to);
          }
        }}
      >
        <SideNav.Toggle />
        <SideNav.Nav defaultSelected="home">
          <NavItem eventKey="home">
            <NavIcon>
              <i className="fa fa-fw fa-home" style={{ fontSize: "1.75em" }} />
            </NavIcon>
            <NavText>Home</NavText>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey="about">
            <NavIcon>
              <i className="fa fa-fw fa-home" style={{ fontSize: "1.75em" }} />
            </NavIcon>
            <NavText>About</NavText>
          </NavItem>
        </SideNav.Nav>
      </SideNav>
      <main>
        {/* <Route path="/" exact component={(props) => <Home />} />
              <Route path="/home" exact component={(props) => <Home />} />
              <Route path="/about" component={(props) => <About />} /> */}
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sidenav-with-react-router-dom-69039375-cpeur